# using BitmapFactory to obtain dimensions on an image can get OutOfMemoryError,

Tags: java, android, image, bitmapfactory

I was trying to find a way to get the dimensions of an image, so that way i knew how the scale it.  The purpose of this was that it wouldnt have these memory issues.

So what i was doing was:

```
BitmapFactory image = new BitmapFactory();
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
image.decodeFile(_path,opts);
if(opts.outHeight > 2048 || opts.outWidth > 2048){
   opts.inSampleSize= 2;
}
VIEW.setImageBitmap(image.decodeFile(_path,opts));
```

The issue is that on the first decode, it will error if the device doesnt have enough memory.

The way i did it was put it in a trycatch block, then added additional statements to the if....   || opts.outHeight == -1 || opts.outWidth == -1){

So what i wanted to know, was that, is there a way to do what i was wanting without sucking up soo much memory on a decode?  I only need to know the original images Height and Width afterall.

Comment: Did  you see this [training](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: I did not, it resolved issues.  I did not know about inJustDecodeBounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a part of BitmapFactory.Options opts there is an attribute inJustDecodeBounds which needs to be set to true to accomplish that fact.

If you set it to true, then all the code works fine.  It isnt building that large image at all and just returns mimetypes, outheight, outwidth, etc.

Further help can be obtained by going to: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html